# What does С# SemaphoreSlim guarantee? Is it full memorybarrier? What we can be sure of code between two different semaphore Wait() and Release()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore, lock-free, memory-barriers

What does С# SemaphoreSlim guarantee? Is it full memory barrier? What we can be sure of code between two different semaphore Wait() and Release()?
Does sequence of different SemaphoreSlim Wait(), Release() and Interlocked methods and Volatile. Write/Read always keep it order in every threads?

```
    public T Dequeue()
    {            
        canReadCountSemaphoreSlim.Wait(); 

        int i = Interlocked.Decrement(ref end);
        T val = Volatile.Read(ref buf[i]);                        

        canWriteCountSemaphoreSlim.Release();            
        return val;            
    }        
    public void Enqueue(T val)        
    {                        
        canWriteCountSemaphoreSlim.Wait();

        int i = Interlocked.Decrement(ref start);
        Volatile.Write(ref buf[i], val);

        canReadCountSemaphoreSlim.Release();            
    }
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using System.Threading;

namespace Program
{
    public class BlockingRingQueue<T> where T: class
    {
        const int BUFSIZE_LOG2 = 10;
        const int BUFSIZE = 1 << BUFSIZE_LOG2;

        T[] buf = new T[BUFSIZE];
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        SemaphoreSlim canReadCountSemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(0);
        SemaphoreSlim canWriteCountSemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(BUFSIZE);

        public T Dequeue()
        {            
            canReadCountSemaphoreSlim.Wait();

            int i = Interlocked.Decrement(ref end);
            i = PositiveMod(i, BUFSIZE);
            T val = Volatile.Read(ref buf[i]);

            canWriteCountSemaphoreSlim.Release();            
            return val;            
        }

        public void Enqueue(T val)        
        {                        
            canWriteCountSemaphoreSlim.Wait();

            int i = Interlocked.Decrement(ref start);
            i = PositiveMod(i, BUFSIZE);
            Volatile.Write(ref buf[i], val);

            canReadCountSemaphoreSlim.Release();            
        }

        static int PositiveMod(int a, int b) => ((a % b) + b) % b;
    } 


    public class Program
    {
        const int READ_THREAD_COUNT = 3;
        static BlockingRingQueue<string> queue = new BlockingRingQueue<string>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(() => Pushing("ABCD")) { Name = "0" }.Start();

            for(int i = 1; i <= READ_THREAD_COUNT; i++)
                    new Thread(Poping) { Name = i.ToString() }.Start();
        }

        public static void Poping() 
        {
            while(true)
            {
                RandSpinWait();
                var val = queue.Dequeue();
                if("" == val)
                    break;

                Console.WriteLine(val + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ' ');
            }
            //Console.WriteLine('!' + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + ' ');
        }

        public static void Pushing(string chars) 
        {
            RandSpinWait();

            var vals = chars.ToCharArray().Select(c => $"{c}")
                .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("",READ_THREAD_COUNT));

            foreach(string v in vals)
                queue.Enqueue(v);            
        }

        public static void RandSpinWait() => Thread.SpinWait(new Random().Next(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify your question since you are currently asking multiple questions.  In addition, you aren't defining the creation of your `SemaphoreSlim` in your code sample, so there is no way to properly determine the behavior.

Comment: It is generalization of this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348662/c-sharp-semaphoreslim-array-elements-read-write-synchronization?noredirect=1#comment106755513_60348662

Comment: Yes, full barrier.  You don't need Interlocked nor Volatile.  Note that the code is not exception-safe, you'd prefer `lock`.  Or better yet, ConcurrentQueue or BlockingCollection.

Comment: @HansPassant: Is full barrier an implementation detail or language guarantee?  In C++, mutex operations only guarantee `acquire` or `release`, not seq_cst.  (In practice on x86, any atomic RMW requires a full barrier, but on other ISAs an LL/SC atomic RMW might only use an acquire load / relaxed store so it could reorder earlier but not later, effectively bringing earlier stuff into the critical section but not letting anything in the critical section escape.)

Comment: (Not that mere acquire and release would be a problem here)

Comment: The task is not to use ready-made blocking collections

Comment: > Yes, full barrier.
What proofs in the documentation?